# Cannot detect click on view wrapped in NSViewRepresentable, if part of a List

Tags: swift, swiftui, appkit

I have a `NSViewRepresentable` over a custom `NSTextField`, and I can't seem to be able to detect clicks on it if it's part of a List. Neither `NSClickGestureRecognizer`, nor `onTapGesture` work.

This is a minimal example exhibiting the problem:

```swift
struct MainView: View {
    let items = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(items, id: \.self) { item in
                TextFieldRepresentable(item: item)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print("onTapGesture")
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TextFieldRepresentable: NSViewRepresentable {
    let item: String

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> some NSView {
        let label = NSTextField(labelWithString: item)
        let clickRecognizer = NSClickGestureRecognizer(target: context.coordinator,
                                                       action: #selector(Coordinator.onClick))
        label.addGestureRecognizer(clickRecognizer)
        return label
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator()
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSViewType, context: Context) { }

    class Coordinator {
        @objc func onClick() {
            print("onClick")
        }
    }
}
```

If I replace `List` by `ForEach`, the `NSClickGestureRecognizer` works, while `onTapGesture` still doesn't.

Is there something more that needs configured when working with lists? `NSClickGestureRecognizer` also works fine when in an AppKit setup, like when the `NSTextField` is part of an `NSTableView`, but not in SwiftUI's `List`.